# DHCP lease table in router shows weird entries when connected to Linux server

Tags: linux, routing, dhcp, mac-address

I have a domestic server where a MitraStar ADSL router is connected to a bunch of mobile devices plus two desktop machines (one Linux and one Windows) connected by Ethernet cables. IP address `192.168.15.2` is reserved for the Windows machine, called `PCWIN` (MAC number `D4:AE:52:FD:E7:C6`), and `192.168.15.5` for the Linux machine, which is called `PC` (MAC number `20:04:0F:FF:2C:93`).

Unfortunately the connection between `PC`and `PCWIN` is erratic. After a few minutes on SSH, `PC` disappears from the routing table and a mystery MAC number shows up associated with the IP I assigned to the server (i.e., `192.168.15.5`).

Right now the router's lease table looks like this:

```
Hostname        MAC Address         IP Address      Time Remaining
iPad1           08:E6:89:9B:C8:6C   192.168.15.4    647 min
PCWIN           D4:AE:52:FD:E7:C6   192.168.15.2    619 min
iPhone1         D4:A3:3D:CA:98:D7   192.168.15.6    677 min
192.168.15.5    DC:35:F1:AC:5C:38   192.168.15.5    596 min ; IP for server "PC"
static-pc0      20:04:0F:FF:2C:93   192.168.15.5    60 min  ; MAC for server "PC"
```

Lines 5 and 6 have stumped me. The MAC address in line 5 does not show up in `ipconfig` in either `PC` or `PCWIN`; I presume this connection is coming from the Linux machine, but have no idea what it is or how exactly it ended up there. Things return to normal when I reboot the router, but the problem soon recurs.

I presume this is all related to the fact that I tried to set up a DNS server on the Linux machine and, frankly, didn't quite know what was I doing--I don't dabble in networking much. The DNS server seems to be working correctly, but the problem persisted after I turned it off.

Well, I must have screwed up something somewhere. Any clues about what happened and how to fix it are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally nailed it. It turns out an old cell phone was connecting to the network. Although I had reserved an IP for the server, the router blithely ignored the reservation and simply kicked the server out of its perch whenever the phone asked it to. Thankfully the rest of the server configuration is OK (or at least doesn't require major surgery).

I knew the router was crappy, but never expected such breathtaking crappiness; it took me quite a while to figure everything out. Hopefully this answer will serve as a cautionary tale for someone out there.